# how to configure "simple-image-browser" plugin for upload image with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to configure  "simple-image-browser" plugin with CKEditor for manage upload image.

I applied this code

```
               CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
                {
                 config.extraPlugins = 'simple-image-browser';
                };
```

but it is not working

Comment: Hello we have resolved this issue by this code http://coursesweb.net/javascript/ckeditor-image-browse_s2